# Can I use InAppSettings with core data instead of plist?

Tags: iphone, core-data, inappsettingskit, inappsettings, inscopeapps

Could I use [InAppSettings](https://bitbucket.org/keegan3d/inappsettings/wiki/Home) as a means to add/edit settings with the tableview style (rounded edges etc), but then once collected use the collected data to persist to/from my core data store?  That is, assuming I already have the core data core in place I would be using InAppSettings as a means to implement the data collection screens essentially.

Is this possible / make sense for InAppSettings?

Another way of looking at the question is whether it is worth trying to integrate InAppSettings into my coredata app as a means to get the nice maintenance screens with rounded edges and the iphone settings app look and feel.

Background - A user in my app can create several view configurations (as many as they wish).  So my thought was whether InAppSettings could be used for the maintenance screens for one view configuration.  The layout of the config data would be roughly like:

- Items (NSArray) // Multiple possible views

  - Item (NSDictionary)   // Could inappsettingskit capture data from here down & pass back to my objective-c calling method - then I could persist it to coredata

    - aString: NSString
    - aString2: NSString
    - aDate: NSDate
    - aDate2: NSDate
    - aBool: BOOL
    - aTI1: NSTimeInterval
    - aTI2: NSTimeInterval
    - Keywords (**NSMutableArray**)

      - keyword: NSString
      - keyword: NSString

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible with [InAppSettingsKit](http://www.inappsettingskit.com) by writing your own `IASKSettingsStore`.